# Fatal Error in Prestashop

Tags: php, apache, prestashop

I'm editing a template in prestashop for one of clients.
I found an error while trying to add a new product from the backend: 
"(*500 Internal Server Error)A server error occurred while loading the tabs: some tabs could not be loaded.Please try again by refreshing the page.If you are still encountering this problem, please check your server logs or contact your hosting provider for assistance.*"

After enabling _PS_MODE_DEV_ to TRUE it gives this error on the "SEO" and "Associations" tabs: Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file C:\xampp\htdocs\relaxme/cache/smarty/compile\95\2b\9c\952b9c1156e995ab664f7186cc0ebddf6ecae0c7.file.header.tpl.php <-- thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\relaxme\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 74

and this one in "Quantities" and "Combinations"

Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file C:\xampp\htdocs\relaxme/cache/smarty/compile\c5\0f\a1\c50fa17a01bbceed324628ae8fe2b71d5e76786a.file.page_header_toolbar.tpl.php <-- thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\relaxme\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 74

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can try to delete all files inside `/cache/smarty`. From what I see you're working on a windows local machine so it might not be related to right permissions on files.

Comment: Indeed, I tried setting all the xampp folder (and subfolders) to both read and writing but it resets itself to read-only. I guess the problem will solve itself once i put the shop online since I can set the file permission with filezilla.